# Why does my JavaScript solution to problem 2 (project euler) show infinity on the console?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

```js
let arr=[0,1];
let sum=0;
for(let i=2;i<4000000;i++) {
    arr.push(arr[i-1]+arr[i-2]);
}

for (let i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    if (arr[i]%2==0) {
        sum+=arr[i];
    }
}

console.log(sum);
```

> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not
> exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

My solution to this question is wrong and I can't figure out why at all. I am not that experienced so please if anyone can explain in a simple way why my code is wrong. What can I do to fix it??

Comment: You very quickly pass the [MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) in the first loop. (on `i === 80` to be precise out of `4000000`)

Comment: Your first loop seems to be wrong, the questions states that you should only consider all terms that have a value less than 4 million, you are instead calculating the first 4 million terms of the sequence

Comment: You also don't need an array for this. Using one will be fairly wasteful of memory.

Comment: @UnholySheep Thank you, I did not even realize this damn. The values themselves should not exceed 4 million right. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Out of curiousity: What is the sum supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** I <s>haven't</s> *hadn't* included code in this answer because I figure the point of what you're doing is to learn to code these things. *(Now you've gotten most of the way there, I did add a solution at the end.)*

---

The problem is that your sums quickly go beyond the range of what JavaScript's number type can represent, reaching the point where they just are represented by `Infinity`. The number type only has 53 effective significant bits in which to hold numbers. You're exceeding that:

```js
let seen4M = false;
let seenInfinity = false;
let arr=[0,1];
let sum=0;
for(let i=2;i<4000000;i++) {
    const num = arr[i-1]+arr[i-2];
    if (!seen4M && num > 4_000_000) {
        console.log(`Too big: ${num}`);
        seen4M = true;
    } else if (!seenInfinity && !isFinite(num)) {
        console.log(`Overflowed just after ${arr[i-1]}`);
        seenInfinity = true;
    }
    arr.push(num);
}

for (let i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    if (arr[i]%2==0) {
        sum+=arr[i];
    }
}

console.log(sum);
```

You're doing four million (minus two) loops, but the question asks you to consider the Fibonacci numbers whose values are less than or equal to four million (4M), which is a very different thing and is reached much more quickly. So instead of (nearly) 4M loops, stop when your code determines that the next number is > 4M.

Also note that there's no reason to use an array for this, and doing so will consume a **lot** of memory unnecessarily. Instead, just remember the penultimate and ultimate values, and shuffle them in the loop. Maintain `sum` in the first loop rather than using a second one.

---

In a comment you showed that you'd solved it using an array but couldn't see how to solve it without using an array. Here's how to do that (see comments):

```js
// The penultimate (second-to-last) Fibonacci number we've done
let pen = 0;
// The ultimate (last) Fibonacci number we've done
let ult = 1;
// The sum so far
let sum = 0;
// A variable for each number as we go
let num;

// Create the next number and keep looping if it's less than or
// equal to four million
while ((num = pen + ult) <= 4_000_000) {
    // We have a new number (`num`), count it if appropriate
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
        sum += num;
    }
    
    // Now that we have a new number, shuffle the last two:
    // our ultimate number is our penultimate number, and
    // our ultimate number is the new one
    pen = ult;
    ult = num;
}
console.log(sum);
```